# Access private content via query string to s3 bucket via Route53 A record

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am attempting to restrict access to file resources stored in an S3 bucket using a query string with a specified time to live, (as outlined here http://birkoff.net/blog/amazon-s3-query-string-authentication-using-php/) to an alias of my bucket.
e.g. in Route53 I have an A record of type Alias, **securefiles.mysite.com** pointing the S3 Alias **securefiles.mysite.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com**.

This works very well with for a file addressed using the standard S3 addresses:
***securefiles.mysite.com.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/privateresource.png?biglongquerystring*** 
or
***securefiles.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com/privateresource.png?biglongquerystring***
but when I attempt to link it using the shorter  ***securefiles.mysite.com/privateresource.png?biglongquerystring***,  it fails with a 403, Access Denied message.

For the sake of investigation, I edited the bucket policy to allow all users access to all bucket resources

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::securefiles.mysite.com/*"
    }
]
```

}

The query string now works to the shorter address but it is no longer secured as all user now have access.

I have also attempted to "not enable web site hosting" to my bucket which again works fine for the full S3 address, ***securefiles.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com/privateresource.png?biglongquerystring***
 but fails with a 404 NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration when addressing the shorter ***securefiles.mysite.com/privateresource.png?biglongquerystring***

Any ideas on how I can securely address files in an S3 bucket from a Route53 A record to  the my S3 bucket alias?

Comment: When building your string to sign, are you using /bucket/foo or just /foo as the path when signing the link to the shorter address?  I think you need the bucket name even though it's not actually in the url path.

Comment: I am using the format /bucketname/pathtofile (securefiles.mysite.com/privateresource.png) as the canonicalisezed resource which is included in the string to sign.

Answer (score 0):

I performed the following tasks:

- Created a bucket in Amazon S3 named `images.my-domain.com`
- Uploaded a file into the bucket
- Created a Record Set in Amazon Route 53 (A record, Alias = Yes, Alias Target = `s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` -- yes, I'm in Sydney too)

**Test 1 - Direct access:** Clicking the object link in Amazon S3 (`s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/images.my-domain.com/picture.jpg`) returned `AccessDenied` as expected, since there are no permissions on the object.

**Test 2 - Direct Pre-Signed URL:** Using a [Pre-Signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) (created via [BucketExplorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/)) on the object in S3 (using the normal S3 URL) successfully provided access to the object. This is to be expected.

**Test 3 - Alias access:** Accessing the object link in Amazon S3, but changing it to use the domain name directly (`images.my-domain.com/picture.jpg`) returned `AccessDenied` as expected.

**Test 4 - Alias access with Pre-Signed URL:** Accessing via the static website URL with Pre-Signed URL **failed**. This is consistent with the problem you have experienced.

Therefore, I agree that it does not seem possible to use a Pre-Signed URL together with a Route 53 alias to a static S3 website.

I then tested it further, using the Amazon S3 static website URL:

**Tst 5 - S3 Static website URL with Pre-Signed URL:** This test tried to access the private file via the static website URL(`images.my-domain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/picture.jpg`) together with the Signature. This also returned `AccessDenied`.

Therefore, the problem doesn't seem to be with the Route 53 URL. Rather, Pre-Signed URLs don't seem to work via the Static Website URL. Since Route 53 uses the Static URL, that fails too.